# MySQL Query SELECT with IF(xxxx already exists) Recursively

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need your help on this custom query, a bit too hard for me. Here is an example for my_table:

```
_______________________________
|  item_name   |  item_slug   |
-------------------------------
| Black Pant   | pant_black   | Select   :  pick first color, 'pant' doesn't exists
| Red Pant     | pant_red     | Variation:  'pant_black'
| Yellow Pant  | pant_yellow  | Variation:  'pant_black'
| Tshirt       | tshirt       | Select   :  'tshirt' exists
| Tshirt Black | tshirt_black | Variation:  'tshirt'
| Tshirt Red   | tshirt_red   | Variation:  'tshirt'
| Tshirt Yellow| tshirt_yellow| Variation:  'tshirt'
-------------------------------
```

The result I try to get is:

If ( 'tshirt' && 'tshirt_black' exists ):

Don't show 'tshirt_black', 'tshirt_red', 'tshirt_yellow' colors and put them in a 'variations' array:

```
tshirt
|   Variations:
|-> tshirt_black
|-> tshirt_red
|-> tshirt_yellow
```

If ( 'pant' doesn't exists && 'pant_black' exists ):

Take the first color found 'pant_black', don't show 'pant_red', 'pant_yellow' colors and put them in a 'variations' array:

```
pant_black
|   Variations:
|-> pant_red
|-> pant_yellow
```

Note: 'pant' doesn't exists, only colors exist.

I managed to make it work when colorless name exists ('tshirt') with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE item_name NOT LIKE '% Black' AND item_name NOT LIKE '% Red' AND item_name NOT LIKE '% Yellow'
```

Then I apply a second query inside a PHP foreach() to put 'Tshirt' variations in a array.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE item_slug LIKE '$item_slug%' AND item_slug != '$item_slug'
```

But I cannot find a way to recursively check if('pant' donesn't exists) then use the first color found as "base". For example 'pant_black'.

The perfect solution would be to make it all-in-one query. What do you think?

EDIT: Edited my post to use 'item_slug' only.

Comment: I don't see what your desired result has to do with the queries that you say are working.  Can you do a better job of explaining what your desired results are?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I edited the post, hope you'll understand now :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get two columns, one with the base name and one with the variation (or NULL) if it is the base name, then you can add a flag to find the base name.

Perhaps this comes close to what you want:

```
select ColorlessName,
       (case when item_name <> ColorlessName then item_name end) as variation
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.item_name
              from my_table t2
              where substring_index(t2.item_slug, '_', 1) = substring_index(t.item_slug, '_', 1)
              order by length(t2.item_name) desc, t2.item_name
              limit 1
             ) as ColorlessName
      from my_table t
     ) t
order by ColorlessName, (variation is null) desc;
```

Comment: I think it's better to use 'item_slug' like you described here. One thing I don't understand is what the 'ColorlessName' column is supposed to be? it doesn't exists in the table

Comment: @hawkidoki . . . It is the best name I can think of for the first column, given your question.

Comment: Fixed it with a LIMIT 1 in the query, but still results are messed up. Some items have multiple underscore _ in their naming (before the last color one)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should really re-write your table schema so that the data is properly [normalised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to fully utilise the capabilities of a relational database such as mysql.

It looks like item_slug is equivalent to [SKU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit).

On that basis, I'd re-write your schema along these lines:

```
create table `products` (
   `product_id` int(10) unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `product_name` varchar(64) not null,
   `product_sku` varchar(32) not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
   KEY `product_name_idx` (`product_name`),
   KEY `product_sku_idx` (`product_sku`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;


create table `options` (
   `option_id` int(10) unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `option_name` varchar(64) not null,
   `option_value` varchar(64) not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;


create table `products_to_options` (
   `product_id` int(10) unsigned not null,
   `option_id` int(10) unsigned not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `option_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `product_id_idfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `option_id_idfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`option_id`) REFERENCES `options` (`option_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

Add some data:

```
INSERT INTO `options` (`option_name`, `option_value`) VALUES
('colour','red'),
('colour','yellow'),
('colour','black'),
('colour','green'),
('colour','blue'),
('size','S'),
('size','M'),
('size','L');

INSERT INTO `products` (`product_name`, `product_sku`) VALUES
('T-Shirt', 'T-red-s'),
('T-Shirt', 'T-red-m'),
('T-Shirt', 'T-red-l'),
('T-Shirt', 'T-green-s'),
('T-Shirt', 'T-green-m'),
('T-Shirt', 'T-green-l'),
('T-Shirt', 'T');

INSERT INTO `products_to_options` (`product_id`, `option_id`) VALUES
(1,1),
(1,6),
(2,1),
(2,7),
(3,1),
(3,8),
(4,4),
(4,6),
(5,4),
(5,7),
(6,4),
(6,8);
```

From there, it's a simple query

```
-- get all products:
SELECT
   product_name,
   product_sku,
   IFNULL(group_concat(option_value), 'none') as attributes
FROM products
LEFT JOIN products_to_options USING(product_id)
LEFT JOIN options USING(option_id)
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY NULL;
```